# Laravel restrict site by password

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5, password-protection

I need to provide authentication my Laravel 5 site by password (no username, just only password). Access to site will possible only if user type correct password. 
It can't be basic server authorization, because I have to implement some design.

I know it is possible to do it with multiple authentication in Laravel, but I have no idea how to make it working with my standard (user and password) authentication in my application.

Can someone help how to do it, please?

Comment: do you want multiple authentication or single authentication will do ?

Comment: If you need to enter password before you enter website, you will most likely want to build authentication middleware infront of `/` or just do basic auth in nginx/apache

Comment: I want two authentications:
- first: enter password to get access to website
- second: normal built-in laravel authentication by user and its password
I need it to provide restriction of use website for people who know password to access website

Comment: @arma "build authentication middleware infront of /" - what do you mean?
It can't be basic auth in nginx/apache because I need to implement some design for that 'input password page'

Comment: do you want to show the password page on entering the website ? Or just the way basic auth works ?

Comment: like, when user enter's the website address he will be shown a page with password input. Once he enters the correct password, laravel auth login page or registration page will show

Comment: Yes, I want to show the password page on entering the website. When user will type correct password that will be saved in session (for the session time), then it will show my homepage of website (there are links on navbar to login and register)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    if (session('password_entered')) {
        return view('homepage');
    }

    return view('enter_password_page');
});

Route::post('/', function () {
    $password_to_website = 'RedMonkey';
    $password = request('password_field');

    if ($password && $password === $password_to_website) {
        session(['password_entered' => true]);
        return view('homepage');
    }

    return back()->withInput()->withErrors(['password' => 'Password is incorect']);
});
```

I have not tried this but the idea is there. You can make middleware out of this or just use it straight up in route/controller.

Comment: I have it already done by this idea. Just created a new middleware and apply that to routes, except input password page.

Comment: @zyx4sdk yes that was the idea, great it worked out for you.

Answer (score 2):

built a manual authentication function to check for only password.

```
    public function authenticate(Request $request)
    {
        $password=$request->get('password');
        if (Auth::attempt(['password' => $password]) )
        {     
            return redirect()->intended('/home');   
        }
        else 
        {
            return redirect('/login');
        }
     }
```

Comment: Thank you, but how can I get it work with my built-in laravel authentication by user and its password (using Auth) ? To store information in session, to prevent asking for password on each page, but only if in session isn't set that current page requester typed already password in that session?

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood your question correctly, you want to have just password authentication on your site without the need for a username. To accomplish this I would do the following:

- Create a user with the email 'passwordlogin@yoursite.com' and your
  desired password
- Update your login form to only require a password

  ```
  <form method="POST" action="/login">
  {!! csrf_field() !!}

  <input type="password" id="fieldPassword" name="password" required>
  <label for="fieldPassword" class="label">Password</label>
  ```
- Change your POST '/login' route to trigger a method called 'passwordLogin' in the Auth\AuthController class

  ```
  <?php
        Route::post('/login', 'Auth\AuthController@passwordLogin');
  ```
- Create a method called 'passwordLogin' in the Auth\AuthController class that uses Auth::attempt() to verify a password. Hardcode the email address to the same one you set in step 1

  ```
  public function passwordLogin(Request $request){

      if($request->has('password')){
          if(Auth::attempt(['email' => 'passwordlogin@yoursite.com', 'password' => $request->input('password')])) {
              // User has the correct password
              return redirect()->('/home');
          }
      }

      // Login failed
      return redirect()->intended('/login');
  }
  ```